# Python, Voice Assistant

Tags: python, browser, voice, assistant, dynamics-al

I use "subprocess" to open a browser window using a voice assistant (in python). Actually, it opens. But how do I write code so that the browser closes with a certain command, for example, "close the browser"?

I use the following code:

```
if cmd == 'open_browser':  
        subprocess.call("explorer    C:\\Users\\Mandalorian\\AppData\\Local\\Yandex\\YandexBrowser\\Application\\browser.exe" , shell=True)
        play("ok")`
```

I have Windows 10, python 3.8.3

I've already tried it but it didn't help:

```
        time.sleep(1)
        os.kill(subprocess.pid, signal.SIGINT)` time.sleep(1)
        os.kill(subprocess.pid, signal.SIGINT)
and
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
        time.sleep(5)
        process.terminate()`
```

Comment: Hello welcome to SO. I would check the voice assistant doc to see how to close it with the phrase "close the browser". And this should be ok. if you need help on that part tell us more ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pywindctl library- https://pypi.org/project/PyWinCtl/
for closing,minimizing,always on top mode, etc..